# Does each Bluetooth device has its own unique MAC Address? How can we access it in an app?

Tags: java, android, c++, c, bluetooth

It is my understanding that there is a universally unique identifier associated with all bluetooth devices from the moment they leave the factory door. For instance, also from you link "If a device is discoverable, it will respond to the discovery request by sharing some information, such as the device name, class, and itsunique MAC address." I am explicitly interested in the MAC address and it had better be universally unique. If my assumption is wrong, then that would be a good thing to know too.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Answer (score 1):

To fetch bluetooth mac address use `BluetoothAdapter` class. You can achieve it by calling `getAddress` method as:

```
String strAddress = null;
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
// if device does not support Bluetooth
if(bluetoothAdapter==null){
    Log.d(TAG,"device doesn't supports bluetooth"); // like in case of emulator
    strAddress = null;
} else
      strAddress = bluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
```